# How to access specific columns and rows of matrices located in a list? (in R)

Tags: r, list, matrix

I'm quite familiar with R but I can't figure this one out. I created the following list of matrices:

```
f=numeric(0)
popM<-list()
popF<-list()
for(i in 1:10){

m<-matrix(sample(c(-1,0,0,1),20,replace=T),ncol=2)
popM[[i]]<-m
}
```

Now I have a list of 10 matrices, and I want to access specific elements of each one. For example, I need to access the first 10 elements of each one. I can do it one by one, with

`popM[[1]][1:5,1:2]`

But how can I simultaneously access the first ten elements of all of my ten matrices?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lapply()`:

```
lapply(popM, "[", 1:5, 1:2) # short for lapply(popM, function(x) x[1:5, 1:2])
```

Comment: This is interesting but is not quite giving the result I want. I want R do display every (or a subset) of the matrices in the list, but only showing, say, the 5 first rows. The output I expect is pretty similar to what alan ocallagham showed, but I don't want an array, I want a list.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe update your post with an example of your expected output.

Comment: Well, when I type ```popM[[1]][1:5,1:2]``` I get the output I want, but only for the matrix number 1. I want one code that would give me a similar output for all my 10 matrices at once, so I don't have to do the same code 10 times. 
The code you gave does't give me that output. It gives something different.

Comment: @Leonardo So you just don't want to print to console? No need to wrap it in a data structure?

Comment: Well, I think it'd be better if we could wrap it in a data structure. Hopefully, a list.

Comment: @Leonardo my solution does return a list. I really don't know what you are expecting.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to be more clear. 
When I type ```popM[[1]][1:5,1:2]``` I get one matrix, right? This matrix is a subset of my original matrix called 'popM[[1]]'. I want that subset to every one of my 10 matrices. I could do this by typing ```popM[[1]][1:5,1:2]```, then typing ```popM[[2]][1:5,1:2]``` and so on. But that would be laborious, because later I'll have to run the same code with more than 1000 matrices.
So, I want one code that would print the subsets of all of my 10 original matrices.

Comment: @Leonardo and is that not what my solution does? How is it different?

Comment: GOSH! I was typing "laply" (with a single P), instead of "lapply" (with double P)!
That makes a HUGE difference. I wasn't paying attention to the exact spell of the word ```lapply```.
Yeah, now it worked. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I feel a little stupid now XD
Well, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As sindri_baldur suggested, you could use `lapply`. You could also just create a tensor/array rather than a list of matrices, and then index this directly.

```r
a <- array(data = sample(c(-1, 0, 0, 1), 200, replace=TRUE), dim = c(10,2,10))
a[1:5, 1:2, ]
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    0
# [2,]    0    0
# [3,]    1   -1
# [4,]    0    0
# [5,]    0    0
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0   -1
# [2,]    0    1
# [3,]    1    0
# [4,]    1    0
# [5,]    1    0
# 
# , , 3
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0   -1
# [2,]    0    0
# [3,]    0   -1
# [4,]    1    0
# [5,]    1   -1
# 
# , , 4
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    0
# [2,]    0    0
# [3,]   -1    0
# [4,]    1   -1
# [5,]    1    0
# 
# , , 5
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    1
# [2,]    0    1
# [3,]    0    1
# [4,]   -1    0
# [5,]   -1    0
# 
# , , 6
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    0
# [2,]   -1    1
# [3,]   -1    0
# [4,]    0    1
# [5,]    0    1
# 
# , , 7
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0   -1
# [2,]    0    0
# [3,]    1    1
# [4,]   -1   -1
# [5,]    0    1
# 
# , , 8
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    0
# [2,]    0    0
# [3,]    0   -1
# [4,]   -1    0
# [5,]    1    0
# 
# , , 9
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    0
# [2,]    1    0
# [3,]    0   -1
# [4,]    1   -1
# [5,]    1   -1
# 
# , , 10
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   -1    1
# [2,]    1    0
# [3,]    0    0
# [4,]    0    1
# [5,]    1   -1
```